# moving to another frame

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to make a hidden object game using actionscript 2.0.

I need help in moving to another frame when all the listed items are already found. Any help guys. I really don't know where to start it.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop();
_root.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (objectcount == 5) { //or however many hidden objects you have
play(); //goes to next frame... add the "stop();" code on the next frame to stop it from continuing to move onto the next frames... additionally you could use _root.goToAndStop(2);
}
}

object1.onPress = function() {
trace("object1found");
objectcount ++; //adds "1" to the number of objects found
object1._visible = false; //hides the object this was just found
}

object2.onPress = function() {
trace("object1found");
objectcount ++; //adds "1" to the number of objects found
object2._visible = false; //hides the object this was just found
}

object3.onPress = function() {
trace("object1found");
objectcount ++; //adds "1" to the number of objects found
object3._visible = false; //hides the object this was just found
}

object4.onPress = function() {
trace("object1found");
objectcount ++; //adds "1" to the number of objects found
object4._visible = false; //hides the object this was just found
}

object5.onPress = function() {
trace("object1found");
objectcount ++; //adds "1" to the number of objects found
object5._visible = false; //hides the object this was just found
}

//and so on...
```